# What does $@ mean in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I'm reading through my .bashrc and noticed the following

```
cd "$@" && some_other_function
```

What does the $@ mean exactly?

Comment: See [unix shell programming special variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206312/unix-shell-programming-special-variables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"$@"` expands to a list of quoted command line parameters.  It is subtly different from `"$*"`:  given

```
set "a b" c d
```

`"$*"` expands to

```
"a b c d"
```

whereas `"$@"` expands to

```
"a b" c d
```

and `$*` (or `$@`) expands to

```
a b c d
```

that is, "`$*"` produces a single string but `"$@"` replicates the original quoting , `$*` loses the quoting.

Answer (score 2):

It's all of the positional parameters, each double-quoted. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#APPREF

Answer (score 1):

From `man bash`:

> @
>   Expands  to  the  positional  parameters, starting from one.  When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word.  That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ...  If the double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the first parameter  is  joined  with  the  beginning part of the original word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last part of the original word.

Answer (score 1):

$@ represents all of the arguments passed to the script.

If you call a script named foo.sh like this:

```
$>  foo.sh boo goo loo
```

The output of *$@* will be this:

```
 > boo goo loo
```

Answer (score 0):

When `$@` is empty, `$@` doesn't expand to an empty string; it is removed altogether. So your test is not:

```
[ -n "" ]
```

but rather:

```
[ -n ]
```

Now `-n` isn't an operator, but just a non-empty string, which always tests as true.